Create a folder inside a SharePoint Online list using graph api
I have a requirement of creating list items inside folders(folders will have unique permissions and hence the requirement). The second requirement is to be able to share the parent folders with external users.
Is it possible to create folders(and share them externally) in the root of a SharePoint Online list via the graph API? I can't seem to find a suitable method to achieve it.
I know this should be doable using the SharePoint REST API but I couldn't find a way to use the API from a client application (e.g. I tried using PowerShell with appregistration/Oauth to get access tokens but it didn't work with SPO, however it worked with graph)
Later edit:
Based on @Sridevi's feedback, I ended up using a combination of PnP and graph commands:

add external user to my tenant using graph api

cls
$SiteURL="https://your_domain.sharepoint.com/sites/your_site/"
$ClientID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

$tenantdomain="your_domain.onmicrosoft.com"
$ClientSecret = "base64 string"
$tenantid="12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789999"
$thumbprint="06D3488F67CC8F90B2CA2C0DE48AB354E0E4259A"

#API info
$loginURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"

# Get an Oauth 2 access token based on client id, secret and tenant domain
$body = @{grant_type="client_credentials";resource=$resource;client_id=$ClientID;client_secret=$ClientSecret}
$oauth = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $loginURL/$tenantdomain/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Body $body

#Let's put the oauth token in the header, where it belongs
$headerParams  = @{'Authorization'="$($oauth.token_type) $($oauth.access_token)"}

#GET 
$uri ="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations"


$body = @{
    invitedUserDisplayName="test";invitedUserEmailAddress="user_email@gmail.com";sendInvitationMessage=$false;inviteRedirectUrls="https://myapp.com"
}
$jsonBody = $body | ConvertTo-Json

$tenantInfo = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $headerParams –Method Post –Verbose -Body $jsonBody)


grant newly added external user permissions to list folder

cls
$SiteURL="https://your_domain.sharepoint.com/sites/your_site/"
$ClientID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

$tenant="your_domain.onmicrosoft.com"
$ClientSecret = "base_64 string here"

#Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -ClientId $ClientID -ClientSecret $ClientSecret

$conn=Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -ClientId $ClientID  -Thumbprint $thumbprint -Tenant $tenant -ReturnConnection
#-UseWebLogin  #



$folder="List folder name"
$externalUser="user_email@gmail.com"
#create HQ folder
#Add-PnPFolder -Name $folder -Folder "Lists/YourList"


#share a folder





#add external user --RENAMED in newer version of PnP to Add-PnPGroupMember
# this api is not working, failing with message "Entra db error: no inviteEmail for invitation"
#Add-PnPUserToGroup -EmailAddress $externalUser -Identity "Test" -Connection $conn -SendEmail


#grant spfolder permissions
$spFolder = Get-PnPFolder -URL ("/sites/extranet/Lists/YourList/"+$folder)
Set-PnPFolderPermission -List "Outprocessing" -Identity $spFolder -User $externalUser -AddRole "Contribute"


Please [edit] the question to include the source code you are trying to make work. [ask]

Initially, register one Entra ID application and grant Sites.ReadWrite.All permission of Application type as below:

I have one document library with below files in SharePoint site named sridemosite :

To create new folder inside above SharePoint Online list using Graph API, you can make use of below PowerShell script:
$siteId = "your-site-id"
$listId = "your-list-id"
$folderName = "DemoFolder"

# Obtain an access token
$tenantId = "your-tenant-id"
$clientId = "your-client-id"
$clientSecret = "your-client-secret"
$authUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$authBody = @{
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $authUrl -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $authBody
$token = $response.access_token

# Create the folder
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$siteId/lists/$listId/drive/root/children"
$body = @{
    name = $folderName
    folder = @{}
    '@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior' = "rename"
}
$jsonBody = $body | ConvertTo-Json
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} -Body $jsonBody -ContentType "application/json"
$response

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in SharePoint Online list where folder created successfully as below:

To share this folder to external user, make use of below script that runs this API:
$folderId = $response.id
$driveId = "driveId"
$externalUserEmail = "smilingxxxxxxx@gmail.com"

# Share the folder
$shareUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$siteId/drives/$driveId/items/$folderId/invite"
$shareBody = @{
    recipients = @(
        @{
            email = $externalUserEmail
        }
    )
    message = "Here's the file you requested."
    requireSignIn = $true
    sendInvitation = $true
    roles = @("read")
    password = $password
    expirationDateTime = $expirationDateTime
}
$jsonShareBody = $shareBody | ConvertTo-Json
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $shareUri -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} -Body $jsonShareBody -ContentType "application/json"

$result

Response:

This will send mail to external user with folder access as below:


Thank you for your post, much appreciated!
But my goal is to create a folder inside the root of a list, not a document library.

This script will work for both! Are you facing any error when you run this code in your environment replacing with your list ID?

Sridevi, to be honest I haven't tried it yet, but saw in your screenshot you ran it against a library. Looking at the code, seems to be ok for a list as well, will try it a bit later and get back. Many thanks!

The $driveid variable in the second script is hardcodded to a string, I assume it should be a drive id of the list, right? So I will need another API call to obtain it...

To get the drive ID, you can list the drives of your SharePoint site with this call GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drives

I think I tried this one in my previous tests but it was not returning the lists, only the document libraries.I will recheck, thank you!

Yes, you are correct...Only document libraries are considered as drives. You won't get lists when you run that API call. AFAIK, it's not possible for folder in lists. You can create folder in document libraries and share with external users as an alternative.

Then I am out of luck, I need it to be a list because I am not storing any files, only metadata.
I will revert to PnP, many thanks for your help anyway!

@AdrianGanea You can share your PnP commands by adding new answer or editing my answer that can be helpful for future readers.

I added the details to my question, I had to use a combination of graph api and pnp because for some reason the Add-PnPGroupMember cmd let was failing due to an entra db error that I couldn't solve. Many thanks for your input!
